# How to send and configure APN Auth Key (.p8 file) in VB.Net

Tags: ios, swift, vb.net, apple-push-notifications

Im facing it difficulty in iOS as well as VB.Net
Not able to find any solutions since yesterday, I am posting it here.
Finding it hard to configure. Any help would be greatful!!

Comment: this is C# code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514289/how-to-use-apns-auth-key-p8-file-in-c

Comment: tried this but i want to configure in ios as well as VB.Net with no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this reference [link](http://thrysoee.dk/apns/) if you have a curl and openssl with Homebrew version.

Other link to run on Node JS code has all steps of creating the Apple Push Notification Authentication Key and setting up a local server. To run Node JS code for sending push notification [link](https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/)

Let me know if you face any issue.